# Firebase query logic not working in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make a query that checks whether a certain name (President or Secretary) exists inside a database. 
The structure of the database is as follows.

[image: Firebase database]

I have this code, but its not working. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query presidentquery = mDatabase.child("validate").child(uid).equalTo("President");
        presidentquery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Candidate p = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Candidate.class);
                        president.setEnabled(false);
                        president.setText("Voted Already");
                    }
                }
                else{

                    president.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            startActivity(new Intent(Home.this, AllCandidates.class));
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: the first if/else statement already checked if the root `President` is exist or not. So, according to your structure, it is exist.

Comment: I also thought it would work, but its not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you know the exact node you want to load, in which case you don't need an `equalTo`. Instead you can look up the node with:

```
Query presidentquery = mDatabase.child("validate").child(uid).child("President");
```

The rest of your code can stay the same.